# How to extend dialogue dynamically to add error msg in vb.net windows form application

Tags: vb.net, windows-forms-designer

I have aLogin dialogue like the image below and I am showing the error messages on top of the dialogue.

[image]
[image]

As you can see I am leaving a rather big empty area on top of the dialogue for these messages(it can be up to 5 lines of text) which does not look good. I would like to remove the empty space on top and add the space in run time when there is an error line added.

I know that it is possible to move each element of the Dialogue down when a new error line is added(e.g. button1.Left += 200, for each element in dialogue), but is there an easier and more practical way to do it?

Comment: its unclear what u wannt???cau u please clarify?

Comment: What about a MultiLine TextBox with a vertical scrollbar?

Comment: There are many many options.  You could put the errors just above the buttons with a `More....` button to expand/show them if the user wants to see them.  Change the form size by a fixed amount, moving the bittons down too to show 3 with a scroller, maybe a flow panel or listview or...

Comment: @zackraiyan I updated.

Comment: @R.Gomez Each error line explains a different problem. e.g. wrong user/pass or invalid file type selected. I guess it doesnt make sense to wtire them all in one line.

Comment: @Plutonix I need all the errors to be visible, because they are different cases. So no scrolling or clicking.  Which of them will do? Can I expand the form from top of it?

Comment: U can store the errors/exceptions in a file or to view the errors within the application , you can use a datagridview/listview/textbox/labels...It's still not clear what you want , but in your comment you said "IF YOU COULD EXPAND THE FORM FROM THE TOP", you can't do that but you can expand the from from below by changing the height promatically, you can place the ERROR LABELS at the bottom as well so that they are visible when the form expands

Comment: @Mary in a MultiLine TextBox you can just write MANY lines (like its name says). So you will just write every error in a line. The textbox gives you the option of scrolling, so you dont need to "move" your forms controls...you could also use a datagridview to have columns as "Error Type", "Error Message" or what ever and present the errors more detailed, You can just generate and dislplay it (DGV or MULTILINE Textbox) at runtime and just fill it with the errors you got.